# Finding parent records with children in LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a 1 to many foreign key related table and I am wondering how to create the following SQL Server query in a Entity Framework LINQ query to only find parent records that have child records?

```
SELECT p.ParentId ,p.ParentName
FROM Parent p JOIN Child c on p.ParentId = c.ParentId
GROUP BY p.ParentId, p.ParentName
HAVING COUNT(c.ParentId) > 0
```

Comment: Please add a sample input and output data.

Comment: Can you share your EF data-model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inner join already limits your resultset to rows where both parent and child are present, so something like below should work:

```html
var parentsWithChildren = (
    from parent in Parent 
 join child in Child on parent.ParentId equals child.ParentId
 select new { parent.ParentId, parent.ParentName } ).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's cleaner than I thought it would be.